# Wrap quotes around many strings in Python

Tags: python

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
etc
```

I have a list of countries, as above, copied from a txt file.  I would like to create a list called `countries` containing all of these entries, without having to go down the list one-by-one wrapping each entry in quotes and add commas.

How can this be done in an efficient and quick way?

Final list should look like:

```
countries = [
"Afghanistan",
"Albanian",
"Algeria"....
]
```

There are lines with 2+ separate strings, `Puerto Rico` for example.  splitlines() seems to separate both words, instead of creating a list entry for each line.

Comment: use `open("countries.txt").readlines().split("\n")`

Comment: @JulienBernu `readlines()` already returns a list. Maybe you wanted to say `.read().split()`?

Comment: _"Wrap them in quotes and add commas"_? What's the final list supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes and commas are for lists and strings specified as *literals* in code. You don't need that for data you are reading programmatically.

Just read the lines and strip off the tailing newlines.

```
with open('countries.text') as src:
    countries = [row.strip('\n') for row in src]
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to add quotes and commas to every entry, just wrap everithing in  triple quotes and then split it.

```
text = \
'''
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
'''
my_list = []
for line in text.strip().split('\n'):
    my_list.append(line)

print my_list
['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria']
```

Or the compact version:

```
my_list = \
'''
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
'''.split()
```

Comment: That loop makes no sense, `text.strip().split('\n')` already is the list you're building.

Comment: `text.strip()` is to avoid empty lines `''` ending in the final list.

Comment: @Chris_Rands `.split()` would also split `Puerto Rico`.

Comment: `.split()` and `.splitlines()` both separate words within country names

Comment: sure it does, the code aims to give a clear description of the procedure since the guy asking the question is clearly new to python. "Explicit is better than implicit"

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your entry is `test.txt` and you want to output in `out.txt`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('test.txt', 'rb') as fr:
        reader = fr.readlines()
        with open('out.txt', 'wb') as fw:
            for line in reader:
                fw.write('\''+line.strip('\n').strip('\r')+'\'\n')
```

This will write in `out.txt`:

```
'Afghanistan'
'Albania'
'Algeria'
'etc'
```

Or if you want to get it in a list:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('test.txt', 'rb') as fr:
        reader = fr.readlines()
        res = list()
        for line in reader:
            res.append(line.strip('\n').strip('\r'))
```

At the end, we have

```
res = ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'etc']
```